# Create additional fields in models on foreign key (Django query)

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=true)
    characteristics = models.ManyToManyField(characteristics, default = '', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class characteristics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=true)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I have some troubles with queryset.
I create 3 persons: Jim, John, Jack.
Then create 4 characteristics: strength, agility, wisdom, intelligence
Connect Jim with strength and agility( he is strong and dexterous)
Connect John with wisdom and intelligence( he is a smart guy)
Connect Jack with strength, agility, wisdom, intelligence( he is jack of all trades)

Output will be like:

```
Jim: strength, agility
John: wisdom, intelligence
Jack: strength, agility, wisdom, intelligence
```

Is there a posibility to add values to these characteristics?
For example:

```
Jim: strength=10 , agility=10
John: wisdom=10, intelligence=10
Jack: strength=9, agility=8, wisdom=8, intelligence=9
```

I think, this values need to be stored in "person" table. I can create additional fields in models.py, but my goal is to make additional field in "person" model when creating new charactaristics.

Thereis a way to make it using 0...1000 empty int fields in "person" model, then giving additional number(like id) to charecteristics and then connect that characteristics id with "person" 0...1000 empty fields

```
from django.db import models

class person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=true)
    characteristics = models.ManyToManyField(characteristics, default = '', on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT)
    char0 = IntegerField(blank=True)
    ...
    char1000 = IntegerField(blank=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class characteristics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=true)
    additional_id = models.BigAutoField
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Is there some elegant way to solve my problem?

Comment: I don't think that **person** table is good place to store the values for each characteristic. Why it shouldn't go in your many-to-many table together with person_id and characteristic_id? If you put the `value` filed in your many-to-many table then you will always know what value each person has for each assigned characteristic.

Comment: @T.Tokic Is it a personal data? If so, why i need to seperate it thru all the database instead of just 1 "person" table? If i will do it like this, i'll need to restruct my database from the beginning. But it's a way too, thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found 4 solutions.

1st(i ought to use it coz haven't got enough time and haven't found other propriate way):

```
models.py

from django.db import models
class person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    characteristics = models.ManyToManyField(characteristics,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    characteristics1 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True) 
    ....   
    characteristics20 = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)

class characteristics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=true)
    additional_id = models.BigAutoField
```

After creating new object in characteristics, object will get additional_id(starts from 1).
Lateron connect characteristics with person.characteristicsX, where (X = characteristics.additional_id).
Then, we can call for object, and sort characteristics by characteristicsX(where X = characteristics.additional_id)

2nd:

```
models.py

from django.db import models

class person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    characteristics = models.ManyToManyField(characteristics,
    null=True,
    on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    characteristics1_type = models.ForeignKey('characteristics', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    characteristics1_value = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True) 
    ....   
    characteristics20_type = models.ForeignKey('characteristics', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    characteristics20_value = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True) 

class characteristics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

May cause troubles, because user can set 2 identical characteristics. Still there is a way to prohibit it using forms or etc.

3rd:

```
models.py

from django.db import models
class person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=False)
    characteristics = models.models.TextField(blank=True)

class characteristics(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
```

Then save values into person.characteristics field using forms. This way can still work, but then it requiers to sort the information from TextField by charecteristics.objects. It'll take some time to setting it well, but will work awesome.

4th:
Use postgreSQL and store an array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try something like this:

```
    class characteristics(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        parameter = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Next you can do:

```
Jim = person.objects.get(name = Jim)
jims_str = characteristics.objects.create(name = "strengh", parameter = 5)
jims_wisdom = characteristics.objects.create(name = "wisdom", parameter = 2)
Jim.characteristics.add(jims_str)
Jim.characteristics.add(jims_wisdom)
Jim.save()
```

I can miss some details, but the main logic might be like that. Different Characteristics (the good practice is to name class names with Capital Latter in Python) might have same names, but unique PrimaryKey, and will be connected to Person model via [M2M relation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).
       **METHOD 2:**
You can edit your `Person` like:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    strength = models.ForeignKey('Strength', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    agility= models.ForeignKey('Agility', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    intelligence= models.ForeignKey('Intelligence', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    wisdom= models.ForeignKey('Wisdom', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
```

Next create 4 models: `Strength, Agility, Wisdom, Intelligence`

```
class Strength(models.Model):
        id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, )        
        parameter = models.SmallIntegerField(default=0)
```

Comment: Its a way too, but every time i want to create new characteristic,  i need to create it in models by hands.  For example, if i need to create new characteristic "constitution", i need to create new model with values, and add this model to person via foreign key. My goal is to allow user create\select characteristics and set values in characteristics in person.

Comment: So this is the 1st method which I have written.

Comment: And the "value" data will be stored in "characteristics" table. Lateron when i'll need to call person with characteristics, it will require more queries to database. Also, users can make mistakes in words or call thing by their own mind (for example: strength and power or dexterity and agility). Giving additional model for characteristics and characteristics value == more and more queries, it's like a snowball. User doesn't need to have so much freedom or they will disturb me more.

Comment: 1) What do u mean saying "when i'll need to call person with characteristics, it will require more queries to database"? You should have the same amount of queries - just get values via select_related(). 2) If you don't want let user to make "mistakes in words" - the best way is predefine set of all possible characteristics earlier. May be try to play with CHOICES in Django. 3) You can also try to play with models.JSONField - it can save your caracteristics in JSON (what is also actually a Python dict)

Comment: 1) Using this simple model, it's the same amount of queries. In my case, it will make more troubles than profit. 2) I dunno amount of characteristics user will use, and if tomorrow at 2a.m  user will ask me to create more models?  Choices is the same as ForeignKey model. 3) I need to have postgreSQL to use JSONField, postgreSQL has ArrayField which can contain multiply number of values. I think that it's easier to create custom field than learn JSON and postgreSQL.

Comment: 1) You can get Person + Characteristics with 1 query. 2) For unknown amount of characteristics - use my 1st method - you easily can add any char. you want, without creating new models. 3) I have never used ArrayField, but the difference between it and JSONField is that ArrayField is unnamed, and in JSON you can store a name of characteristics and its value.

Comment: 1)Queries will be more troublesome,+more requests to database, it's worth it. 2) Everytime user will create new characteristic, he will create new row in database(for example: strength=10, strength=15, strength=20; in total there will be 3 positions in database: strength=10, strength=15, strength=20; if there will be 10000 persons with unique characteristic value=>10000 useless rows in characteristic table=>more difficult to manipulate with person+characteristics objects when smth goes wrong.3) That's it, i just needed a field which can contain multiply amount of values. Still need postgreSQL.

Comment: 1)You cant do complicated things with only simple queries. If you want do something custom- you need more complication in database. 2)That rows wouldn't be "useless"- they have specific role- to store values of your characteristics. And what is the difference how many rows does your db contain? 10k its even not a big amount.  And if you plan that your project will collect so many users who create 10k rows in your database - that's a good result, so you have to think about good db design for the future. And models like you have written at the beginning- that's bad design. 3)It's just an option.

Comment: 1)actually, I can make it easy to use for one query. If I need smth cannot be done with sqlite3, I can use different database or create custom fields and way to read data from this fields. 2) it doesn't matter how many rows my database will contain, it will be a lot of rubbish in data later on.3) it's a way, not an option. I have already done it with arrayfield, it works, it's simple, it's easy to read.